# write htaccess to hide html file extension + make http go to https + make xyz.com go to www.xyz.com

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following code in a htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain-name.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I don't know anything about htaccess files but this appears to do the following:

• make domain-name.com go to www.domain-name.com

and

• make http://www.domain-name.com go to https://www.domain-name.com

so everything is going to https://www.domain-name.com  Which is what I want.

However how do I also hide the .html file endings? So domain-name.com/about.html becomes domain-name/about

I've found the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But don't know how to combine the two bits of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these rules in your Apache config or site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /file.html to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally rewrite /file to /file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Big thank you. In my html when linking to say the about page do I link to <a href="about.html">About</a> or <a href="about">About</a> ?

Comment: better to have `<a href="about">About</a>` but these rules will redirect old html links to ones without `.html`

Comment: Will this slow the loading of the web pages down? I'm wondering if I'm seeing a flicker as the page loads and it seems slower

Comment: even though they are redirecting pages?

Comment: **All of these rules** have no bearing on page load speed.

Comment: So the /about.html page is not being loaded and then it gets "redirected" or "changed" to /about ?

Comment: What happens when you just try to load `/about`? Also I suggest you to test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.